# Are there any AWS S3 browser for ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, aws

Are there any AWS S3 browser for ubuntu 20.04?

I saw a lot of options but most of the links are dead or are not maintained .

Comment: There are none in active development but, if you don't mind mounting the S3 bucket to a directory then using a standard file manager, then S3FS might be what you're looking for. The only other reliable option I can think of would be `s3cmd`, but that's a command line tool rather than something visual.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse by CLI using [Rclone](https://rclone.org/), it's a great open-source way to link cloud services with on device files, it can serve an experimental web [GUI](https://rclone.org/gui/) or you can mount the bucket as a folder